# Excel change text box color based on value

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I need to change the background color of a text box based on the value in that box which is being retrieved from another page. As I am finding out, you cannot do conditional formatting with text boxes, so the only way is with VBA. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set up the code to make this work. I tried opening the VBA viewer and using this code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

If TextBox1.Value = "" Or Not "1" Or Not "2" Or Not "3" Then _

TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

If TextBox1.Value = "1" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

If TextBox1.Value = "2" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)

If TextBox1.Value = "3" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)

End Sub
```

I get some error that says Object required and one that says block if without end if? I found the code on a forum and the user had success, so I know it should work. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should help you :

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    With Sheets("Sheet3").OLEObjects("TextBox1").Object
        Select Case .Value
            Case Is = vbNullString 'same as ""
                .BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            Case Is = 1
                .BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Case Is = 2
                .BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            Case Is = 3
                .BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
            Case Else
                .BackColor = RGB(126, 126, 126)
        End Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is it correct to select the text box, go to view code, and paste this in? I tried your code above and it now just gives me the object required error... Thanks again @R3uK

Comment: So it isn't in a UserForm? It is an ActiveX control?

Comment: It most probably is, so take a look at the edit and change `SheetName` to your actual Sheet's name and this should work

Comment: The first code that you gave me was working when I changed it to an active X control text box. However, I can't link the value from another cell with active X, so it would be best to make it work with a regular text box. With the new code, it says object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Ok this must be working because the previous code where for the others kind of TextBox, so this is the one! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an Object required error because you put your code in an object where Textbox1 doesn't exist. Put your code into either a userform or a worksheet where there is a Textbox named "Textbox1".

To solve the "If without End If" issue change the following:

```
If TextBox1.Value = "" Or Not "1" Or Not "2" Or Not "3" Then _

TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

To this:

```
If TextBox1.Value = "" Or Not "1" Or Not "2" Or Not "3" Then _
TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

I would personally use a Select Case statement like the following, but what you have works other than that one line.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Select Case TextBox1.Value
        Case "1": TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case "2": TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Case "3": TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        Case Else: TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I have the text box named TextBox1 in the worksheet that I'm trying to edit. Is there a way to get this to work with a regular text box instead of an active x control? I can't link the value to another worksheet with active x

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using a User form where you need the Textbox to change color based on the information in it.

I am currently working on the same thing and I have come with the following solution:

For UserForm1 with 4 textboxes listed 1 - 4

```
Private Sub Textbox1_Change()
 If TextBox1.Text = "A" Then
TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 32, 96)
 ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "B" Then
TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 112, 192)
  ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "C" Then
TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(189, 215, 238)
  ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "D" Then
TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 176, 240)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Textbox2_Change()
 If TextBox2.Text = "A" Then
TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(0, 32, 96)
TextBox2.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
 ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "B" Then
TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(0, 112, 192)
  ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "C" Then
TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(189, 215, 238)
  ElseIf TextBox2.Text = "D" Then
TextBox2.BackColor = RGB(0, 176, 240)
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Textbox3_Change()
 If TextBox3.Text = "A" Then
TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(0, 32, 96)
 ElseIf TextBox3.Text = "B" Then
TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(0, 112, 192)
  ElseIf TextBox3.Text = "C" Then
TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(189, 215, 238)
  ElseIf TextBox3.Text = "D" Then
TextBox3.BackColor = RGB(0, 176, 240)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Textbox4_Change()
 If TextBox4.Text = "A" Then
TextBox4.BackColor = RGB(0, 32, 96)
 ElseIf TextBox4.Text = "B" Then
TextBox4.BackColor = RGB(0, 112, 192)
  ElseIf TextBox4.Text = "C" Then
TextBox4.BackColor = RGB(189, 215, 238)
  ElseIf TextBox4.Text = "D" Then
TextBox4.BackColor = RGB(0, 176, 240)
    End If
End Sub
```

The final result is as follows:

[image: Formatting example]