# Change Color of Text based on Extension File Type

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a form created in Visual Studio 2019. I have several text boxes that display paths to specific files. How can I change the color of these paths based on what type of file extension is being loaded?

EX. if the path string is routed to a .xls file --> turn text green, if not a .xls file turn text red.

EDIT: I am using WinForms, VB.Net.

Comment: Sounds like you're working with VB.Net, not VBA - please update tags to reflect this.

Comment: What kind o form? (WinForms, WPF, WebForms, or something else?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624544/excel-change-text-box-color-based-on-value